# Drawbacks to the method of loci for memorization

Tags: memory

The [method of loci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_loci) is a famous way of memorizing information by associating each memorized item in a spatial way.  There's plenty of content out there describing how to do it.  I'm wondering what the drawbacks might be.

Has anyone done any studies into issues that arise for people who memorize details using the method of loci?  For example, perhaps there are sets which one cannot memorize because one already memorized a related set and committed it to memory?  Or perhaps one might create hazardous paths which contain harmful memories which one would like to unlearn but cannot, causing trauma?

As a non-scientific reasoning, it strikes me as there must be some drawbacks, or society would have figured this out long ago and would have taught us all to memorize everything this way.

Comment: I am in the middle of a move, so I don't have access to the source (most likely the Oxford handbook of memory),  in general there is a trade off in between the effort put into encoding something through mnemonics and the particulars of each method, in the case of loci, it would be the effort needed for creating a memory palace in the first place as well as the training,upkeep and conflict with the inhabitant items. Moonwalking with Einstein(Foer) talks about it anecdotally, so in essence time and reliability work against it.